# Xcode iOS Camera Exposure Region

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is there a way to limit the exposure region on the iPhone camera to a specified square, and not just a center point? Bright or dark areas outside my region of interest are affecting the overall exposure. Right now I'm using exposurePointOfInterest, but this only allows for a center point to be specified.

Comment: I don't need to use exposurePointOfInterest.  Just some way of selecting a square region for exposure.  And not just a center point as used in exposurePointOfInterest

Comment: Hello, I'm running into a similar issue. if there is a darker and brighter image on the camera screen, it adjusts the exposure to the dark image and the brighter part gets overexposed. I'd like to know how you manage the problem....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can pass a CGPoint to the method.

example:

```
- (void) focusAtPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [[self videoInput] device];
    if ([device isFocusPointOfInterestSupported] && [device isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus]) {
        NSError *error;
        if ([device lockForConfiguration:&error]) {
            [device setFocusPointOfInterest:point];
              [device exposurePointOfInterest:location];
            [device setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus];
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        } else {
            id delegate = [self delegate];
            if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(acquiringDeviceLockFailedWithError:)]) {
                [delegate acquiringDeviceLockFailedWithError:error];
            }

        }        

    }

}
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDevice/exposurePointOfInterestSupported

Comment: Do you know if I can pass a CGRect to exposurePointOfInterest?  I want to select a square region of interest, and not just a point

Comment: nope, just a cgpoint. `@property(nonatomic) CGPoint exposurePointOfInterest`

Comment: Also remember that both `exposurePointOfInterest` and `focusPointOfInterest` are CGPoints between (0,0) and (1,1). Regardless of the device's current orientation, (0,0) is the upper left hand corner and (1,1) is the lower right hand corner of the device in the Landscape Right orientation.